# Show previous text even after click event on Android

Tags: java, android

Here is my image button Click action below.

It will show "1 null" after clicked, while holding the button it shows rightAnswer. I want to illustrate the saved string of questionLabel after finishing the holding button.

What I want to do is that define "sharedFact" before Action_down happens and keep that text to show after the user button untouched.

The "rightAnswer" should be only shown while the user holding imageButton

I tried to use normal String text like "test", it works, however String sharedFact = questionLabel.getText().toString();

↑ is not working like what I thought, what is the problem and how to fix?

```
findViewById(R.id.image_button_check).setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        String sharedFact = null;
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                sharedFact = questionLabel.getText().toString();
                questionLabel.setText(rightAnswer);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //Here is only test "1" is for identify this code is working
                //How can I save questionLabel Text before action down but inside click action?
                questionLabel.setText(1 + sharedFact);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your definition from inside the function to a class data member.

```
String sharedFact = null;
onCreate(){
// your code

findViewById(R.id.image_button_check).setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                sharedFact = questionLabel.getText().toString();
                questionLabel.setText(rightAnswer);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //Here is only test "1" is for identify this code is working
                //How can I save questionLabel Text before action down but inside click action?
                questionLabel.setText(1 + sharedFact);
                sharedFact = null
                break;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: At the same time, I realised my silly mistake. The same way worked, thanks